# shadow not rendering

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

This is driving me insane !

I have been making a simple scene for a point&click game. Most of the models are 'done', and I now want to set up the lighting.
I am using Toon shaders for my models. I have added 1 hemi lamp, and 1 sun in my scene.

When I look through the camera, in the editor, I can see shadows in the sofa (left img). When I render the scene (Blender internal) there are no shadows (right img). And why is there such a difference in the way the scene looks ?

What settings could I inadvertently have changed ???
I have been trying to fix this for 2 days already ... I am getting desperate  :-)

Thanks for your help !

[image: in editor image]
[image: rendered image]

Comment: could you supply the .blend file?

Comment: I have found what is causing this, but I don't understand why ... My room has a ceiling ... I had both lamps inside the room, but apparently you cannot do that  ?! The moment I render without the ceiling, I have shadows. Render the roof as well, and the shadows are gone (even with both lamps inside the room)

So, how can I solve this ? Should I use point lights instead of a sun ???

Comment: Are you sure your lights and objects are on the same layer ?

Comment: Sun/hemi lights are always at infinity. Their location does not matter, only rotation. If you change them to a point light, do things work as expected?

Comment: Aleph : I don't think lights & objects have to be on the same layer, as long as you don't check 'this layer only' for the light ...
. 
JtheNinja : yes ... that worked, but the lighting effect is not uniform that way. I'm now trying with area lights. That seems to be the way to go !

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but --

are you sure you have shadows turned on in the render panel?

Under the render panel (the one with the little "camera" icon), scroll down to the "Shading" roll-out, and be sure you have "Shadows" checked.

Otherwise your shadows won't render.

Shadows are a two-step thing.  Once you've refined them in your lighting panel, be sure to turn them on in your render panel.